# The player, that support in IOS(Apple)

Tags: ios, media-player, offline

I'm using Shaka payer for offline storage and playback using offline API. That is supporting all browsers in Desktop. And in Android mobile. But that is not supporting in IOS(Apple). Please suggest me a player that will support in IOS for offline storage and playback.

Comment: You can use AVPlayer.

Comment: Nothing documentation is there in AVPlayer for offline storage and playback.